# Как сделать затемнённое изображение?

Tags: html, css

[image: Скриншот сайта]

Как сделать затемнённое изображение как на фото?

Comment: сделайте слой поверх изображения и задайте ему нужный цвет и прозрачность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается на `html и css`. В css главное для картинки это `position:absolute;`

`Absolute` указывает, что элемент абсолютно позиционирован, при этом другие элементы отображаются на веб-странице словно абсолютно позиционированного элемента и нет. Положение элемента задается свойствами `left, top, right и bottom`, также на положение влияет значение свойства `position` родительского элемента.

```css
#outer-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 194px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#outer-box img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#outer-box #inner-box {
  background: #FD8698;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

#outer-box #inner-box p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-family: 'arial';
  text-align: center;
}

#outer-box:hover #inner-box {
  opacity: .9;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-box">
  <img src="https://img.fonwall.ru/o/5y/eiffel-tower-paris-france-eyfeleva-bashnya-7n74.jpg" />
  <div id="inner-box">
    <p>Почему именно мы?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это называется overlay

Comment: спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью CSS. Подложите под изображение чёрный фон и уменьшайте прозрачность изображения с помощью, к примеру, `opacirity: 0.9`.

Comment: а как подложить фон под изображение?

Comment: Для `div` изображения сделайте CSS `background: #000`.

Comment: Свойства `opacirity` не существет ))